# python program runs only from terminal, how to turn localhost to REAL web server

Tags: python, ssh, cron, localhost, webserver

I have the following program in python 3 and i try to make it run from
crontab, as a service, on init.d and its not run or gives an error "connection closed from host".

When i start it from terminal it works perfectly!
What i do wrong?
I make it with loop, because i want to start again if it fails, as a test.

```
import os
import time
import datetime
print("Turn online the localhost")

for i in range (0, 100):
    starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Ready to run")
    os.system('ssh -o serveraliveinterval=60 -R art:80:localhost:80 serveo.net')
    endtime= datetime.datetime.now()
    diff = endtime - starttime
    print(i+1,".Up for = ",diff)
```

As you understand i like to make live a small site that i have made. If its any other way to do that please tell me
Thank you!